# How to configure external vendor SSL certs, keystores and properties into JBoss 7.1

Tags: java, ssl, jboss

I am in the process of configuring in vendor SSL certs, keystores and properties into JBoss 7.1 but was not successful.

Here is how I tried.

1) Copied properties directory(it has multiple property files provided by the vendor) to /opt/jboss/modules/com/companyname/main.

2) Created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml under webapp/WEB-INF with the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="com.companyname" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

3) Added module.xml(/opt/jboss/modules/com/companyname/main) with the following content

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.companyname">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="./properties"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

4) Copied certs and keystores folder provided by vendor under /test/project directory.

5) Added the following entry in standalone.xml  just after .... tag

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="/test/project/certs"/>
</system-properties>
```

I not seeing any errors in the log during startup but it is failing to invoke the external webservice.

Am i missing any other configuration? Any help will be appreciated.